# Flutter how to change TextField borders after certain condition

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

so I'm trying to create a SignUp form where there are textfields. What I want to do is, if the SignUp button is pressed and it has empty fields in it, then the border of `TextField` should change from green to red and also put a `TextHint` saying "This field is empty"

I could only see `TextEditingController` which controls only Text part of the `TextField`.

So, how to change border of a TextField AFTER say an event?

```
TextField(
  controller: _name,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: ' NAME ',
    labelStyle: TextStyle(
      fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      color: Colors.grey),
    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green),
    ),
  ),
),
```

I want that green to be red if the field is empty after button is pressed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the borderDecoration property I made it into a var so I can then later use it with the ternary operator syntax to provide the (boolean)red underline if empty or otherwise. I used the 'enabledBorder' property to change the underlineborder to red. I then created a var for the "TextHint" if empty as 'errorText' that will appear under the textfield or be empty if input has text.

To make this modular, what you can do is actually put the 'borderDecoration' var in another folder and just import it here.

```
 final _name = TextEditingController();
      final borderDecoration = InputDecoration(
        labelText: ' NAME ',
        labelStyle: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: Colors.grey),
        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green),
        ),
      );
      String errorText = '';
      bool redUnderLine = false;

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("title"),
          ),
          body: Column(children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            TextField(
                controller: _name,
                decoration: redUnderLine
                    ? borderDecoration.copyWith(
                        enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
                      )
                    : borderDecoration),
            Text(errorText, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
            SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_name.value.text.isEmpty) {
                    setState(() => redUnderLine = true);
                    setState(() => errorText = "This field is empty");
                  } else {
                    setState(() => redUnderLine = false);
                    setState(() => errorText = "");
                  }
                },
                child: Text("SignUp"))
          ]),
        );
      }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just a quick question though, is there a way to remove that `lableText: 'Name'` from `var` `boxdecoration` and put directly into the `TextField`? Because I intend to use the same `boxdecoration` to all remianing fields and don't want to create a `boxdecoration` for every other fields.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out a way. I added `labelText: Name` to `borderDecoration.copyWith(..)` and also changed `: borderDecoration),` to `borderDecoration.copyWith( labelText: "NAME")`. That worked and solved my problem.

Comment: Great, no problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use separate bool variable to do so. you set bool to true is no data is filled and then it will show error.

Following full code may help you more.

```
 TextEditingController _name = TextEditingController();
  bool _validateName = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              controller: _name,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: ' NAME ',
                errorText: _validateName ? "please enter name" : null,
                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
                focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("submit"),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _name.value.text.isEmpty
                      ? _validateName = true
                      : _validateName = false;
                });
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```